# What does "$[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL]" refer to when setting Google Load Balancer towards a GCP Storage Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I am currently trying to learn how to set up (multiple) redirects in Google HTTP(S) Load Balancer, as seen in the image below:

[image: overview image of google load balancer advanced routes]

It does give an example on the right side bar:

```
defaultService: $[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL]
name: matcher1
routeRules:
  - matchRules:
      - prefixMatch: /
    priority: $[PRIORITY]
    urlRedirect:
      hostRedirect: $[REDIRECT_HOST]
      pathRedirect: $[REDIRECT_PATH]
      redirectResponseCode: FOUND,
      stripQuery: True
```

However, if you check the documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/traffic-director/docs/traffic-control?&_ga=2.85230937.-1562985328.1644261693#configuring_traffic_control

It does not actually specify for example what `$[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL]` should be. What does that refer to?

My Load Balancer is pointing towards a GCP Bucket backend.

Is there an example YAML I can learn from?

Comment: No worries, you are in a black hole!! You have access to new feature, not yet officially announced (Today, October 11th, 9am PT, Cloud Next Keynote!). So the  documentation is not up to date yet, but you can play with new features! Have a break and wait a bit!

Comment: You can still find similarities in that page: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management-global#advanced_host_path_and_route_rule

Comment: I did see the samples on that page, but still don't know what "defaultService" to use for a GCP Bucket backend.

Comment: In fact, when you set up a URL MAPS in HTTPS Load Balancer, you have a default service on which the default path "/" binded to a default url is routed. "Happy path", "default path", "safe path", name it as you which, but keep in mind that the default route if none of the subsequent matchers match your request URL

Answer (score 2):

I found this a little bit confusing as well, most of the documentation is centered around backend services rather than backend buckets.
If it helps anyone else, you can get the URI of your buckets with a gcloud command as follows:

```
gcloud compute backend-buckets list --uri
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `gcloud compute backend-services list --uri` helped me, thanks for pointing the correct way

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of the application, it could be created directly, but now you have to use yml, which I think is a step backwards

Answer (score 0):

`$[DEFAULT_SERVICE_URL]` is the [default backend service](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#url_map_defaults) or in your case, the default backend bucket if none of the path matchers or host rules match the incoming URL.

You can find a few examples from the [documention](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management-global#advanced_host_path_and_route_rule) as previously stated. You may also check  this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74352537/google-cloud-load-balancer-routing-roles-not-working) for additional YAML sample.