# Google Cloud load balancer routing roles not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

[image]

I have two backend services(**X backend service** and **Y backend service**) for which I have configured a load balancer and created some routing rules as can be seen in the photo.
My goal:

- Access *dev.somedomain.io* -> redirects to **X backend service**
- Access *dev.somedomain.io/shopify* -> redirects to **Y backend service**
- Access *dev.somedomain.io/api* -> redirects to **X backend service**

Actual result:

- When I try to load:  *dev.somedomain.io* everything seems to work fine and I get can see
  swagger as in dev.somedomain.io/swagger/index.html.
- When I try to load:  *dev.somedomain.io/api* I get a 404 and nothing loads.
- When I try to load:  *dev.somedomain.io/shopify* I get a 404 and nothing loads.

From what I can see only the last route seems to get matched (the one with **/*** as a path).
Not sure what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I needed to specify the action and url rewrite for the above routes to work. But since there is no option to specify those from the UI I needed to select the advanced route configuration and need to provide it as YAML as the following:

```
defaultService: projects/some-project/global/backendServices/x-api-dev-backend-service
name: path-matcher-1
pathRules:
- paths:
  - /shopify/*
  service: projects/some-project/global/backendServices/y-dev-backend-service
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /
- paths:
  - /api/*
  service: projects/some-project/global/backendServices/x-dev-backend-service
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and adding the `routeAction` with a fixed `pathPrefixRewrite` solved it. It would be intuitive that the path prefix was stripped by default, but apparently it isn't. It's so strange that there's no GUI to adjust this. Thanks for sharing!